# ReactDOM.render(<Cmp/>,<Cmp/>, element); gives Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I want to add a dropdown on my application and

I have added the below codes to getting an error on it in the index.js file to please anyone help with it.

```
import DropdownList from 'react-widgets/lib/DropdownList';
ReactDOM.render(<App/>,<DropdownList/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Error: Target container is not a DOM element[image].[image]

Comment: This probably means you don't have an element with the ID of 'root'. A screenshot of your code would help.

Comment: https://anilkumar-aitechindia.tinytake.com/tt/NDcwOTU5N18xNDkxMDQzNg

Comment: please find the link for code screenshots its not worked while i add the dropdownlist on render ReactDOM.render(<App/>,<DropdownList/>, document.getElementById('root'));

Comment: can you edit your question and put that screenshot in there? it would help other people answer too. Also, where is your html?

Comment: sure Morgan smith

Comment: Screenshots of code are actually *[discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).*

Comment: Screenshots of code are actually *[discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).*  Thanks for posting that, but I recommend posting the code itself in the future.

Comment: `ReactDOM.render` takes only two arguments one component and the other where to render it... You have 2 components `<App />` and `<DropdownList />`... It's thinking that the second component is the DOM node

Comment: Oh, wow, didn't even see that because it wasn't formatted.  Do as suggested above, change your code to `ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('root'));`.

Comment: The `<DropdownList />` component needs to be rendered inside `<App />` - I'd suggest a basic React tutorial...